# Connecting to ActiveMQ (or SQS) on R

Tags: r, activemq-classic, message-queue, amazon-sqs

I can't find any code that works and isn't outdated for modern revisions of R. Some GitHub repository imports work (added below), but none are meant for ActiveMQ specifically.

```
remotes::install_github("cloudyr/aws.s3")
​remotes::install_github("Azure/AzureQstor")
​install.packages("rzmq")​
remotes::install_github("lecardozo/rworker")
```

I need it to work on R version 3.6.3.
The closest I got to have it working is through Apache's referred code:

```
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="C:/Program Files/AdoptOpenJDK/jre-8.0.242.08-hotspot")  #custom provision of Java SDK
library("rJava")
.jinit()
attach(javaImport(c("javax.jms", "org.apache.activemq")))
connFactory <- new(ActiveMQConnectionFactory)  # ERROR: R doesn't recognize "new"
conn <- connFactory$createConnection()
sess <- conn$createSession(FALSE, Session$AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)
dest <- sess$createQueue("SampleQueue")
prod <- sess$createProducer(dest)
msg <- sess$createTextMessage("Simples Assim")
prod$send(msg)
conn$close()
```

I could compromise for Amazon-SQS since I'm mainly restricted to Amazon MQ services.
If there's no library for me to import, what alternative approach could I take?

Comment: You could potentially use STOMP. It's a very simple protocol with clients in lots of different languages/environments.

Comment: None of the STOMP libraries / documentations I tried were functional while fitting a modern version of R (3.6.3 or higher). If you know any proper documentation, could you please reference me to it?

Comment: I've not really ever worked with R before. However, as a broker developer I know that STOMP is often used in non-traditional use-cases because it has a clear specification and is fairly easy to implement. If you can't even get a functioning STOMP client it seems unlikely to me that you'd find a more complex client that works (e.g. AMQP, OpenWire, MQTT).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked:

```
library("Rjms")
attach(javaImport(c("java.lang", "javax.jms", "org.apache.activemq")))
connFactory <- new(ActiveMQConnectionFactory)
conn <- connFactory$createConnection()
sess <- conn$createSession(FALSE, Session$AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)
dest <- sess$createQueue("SampleQueue")
cons <- sess$createConsumer(dest)
conn$start()
msg <- cons$receive()
System$out$println(msg)
conn$close()
```